# React Native: For the Image Component, do we really need to define a dimension?

Tags: image, react-native

I'm a bit baffled at this.

It seems that my image wont display on the android virtual device unless I define a width and height.

i basically have the following code:

```
   <Image source={pic}  />
   <Image source={pic}  style={{width:100,height:100}} />
```

Only the 2nd image would display on the AVD, as well as on the rnplay.org site
https://rnplay.org/apps/w5-GSQ

[image]

but if i try the code on the REACT NATIVE tutorial website and simulate it, it seems to work fine..
[image]

What the heck's going on? Am I missing something here?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The react-native docs uses react-native-web to run the examples. react-native-web don't support either height or width on the source atm. See this issue - https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/10

This probably explains why the height,width is not specified in the react-native example code, but is required in the docs.

Comment: I see. thanks.. followup question.. so how the heck can i make the image auto size then if i have to set the fixed W/H? any ideas?

Comment: Set the size according to the width of the device or whatever component you are building. The height should be set according to what aspect ratio you like ie 4/3. There are two apis available to help you. Dimensions and PixelRatio. The Dimensions.get('window') will return 'logical' dimensions of the display, so you have to multiply with the PixelRatio.get() to get the physical dimensions that the Image components needs along with the  resizeMode="contain" prop.